# Concat null columns data with actual data in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have set of columns need to be merged into single column where some columns have data and some don't have where it should be joined with the data to single column

Input is like this:

[image]

output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using apply method we can merge these columns, as below;

```
cols = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5']

df['Value']=df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_string(index =False,na_rep=''),axis=1).replace({"\n":''},regex=True)

df.drop(cols, axis=1, inplace=True)

df
```

Comment: Please accompany your answer with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

for a simple concatenation, you can use the below code

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', ''], ['nick', 'vuchic'], ['juli', '']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'LastName'])
print(df)

df['FullName']=df['Name']+' '+df['LastName']
  
# print dataframe.
print(df)
```